# I'm trying to installl homebrew before I install RVM but i'm having difficult installing homebrew.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal, homebrew

Here is how my cod eon terminal showed up after it failed to download homebrew.

Last login: Tue Feb 18 21:49:54 on ttys000
         Alexs-MacBook-Air:~ arodriguez2012$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL               https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
          ==> This script will install:
      /usr/local/bin/brew
      /usr/local/Library/...
        /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

```
      Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
         ==> Installing the Command Line Tools (expect a GUI popup): 

          ==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --install
      Usage: xcode-select -print-path
         or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
       or: xcode-select -version
    Arguments:
         -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
          -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
          -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
     Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --install
       Alexs-MacBook-Air:~ arodriguez2012$
```

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed?

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Xcode Application and go to Preferences.  Under Locations, click 
Command Line Tools drop down and select the newest version and it will prompt you to enter your password.  Close Xcode and then go ahead with your HomeBrew install.